# How do I generate code with flex/bison and put it to file

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing a translator for uni project which should translate given Pascal code into assembler code using flex/bison. I've written parser and lexer, which generates symbol table (atm works correctly only without procedures and functions). And my question is, how do I generate assembler code from it and print it to file.

Here is my lexer:

```
%{
#include "parser.tab.h"
#include <string.h>
#define YY_FLEX_DEBUG 1
%}

letter      [a-zA-Z]
digit       [0-9]
ID          {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
delim       [ \t\n]
NUM         {digit}+(\.{digit}+)?(E[+\-]?(digit)+)?
ws          {delim}+

%%
{ws}        {                                           }
if          {return(IF);                                }
then        {return(THEN);                              }
else        {return(ELSE);                              }
{NUM}       {yylval.stringValue = strdup(yytext); return(NUM);          }
"<"         {yylval.stringValue = "<"; return(RELOP);   }
"<="        {yylval.stringValue = "<="; return(RELOP);  }
"="         {yylval.stringValue = "="; return(RELOP);   }
">"         {yylval.stringValue = ">"; return(RELOP);   }
">="        {yylval.stringValue = ">="; return(RELOP);  }
"<>"        {yylval.stringValue = "<>"; return(RELOP);  }
":="        {return(ASSIGNOP);                          }
do          {return(DO);                                }
program     {return(PROGRAM);                           }
var         {return(VAR);                               }
array       {return(ARRAY);                             }
of          {return(OF);                                }
integer     {return(INTEGER);                           }
real        {return(REAL);                              }
function    {return(FUNCTION);                          }
procedure   {return(PROCEDURE);                         }
begin       {return(START);                             }
end         {return(END);                               }
div         {yylval.stringValue = "div"; return(MULOP); }
mod         {yylval.stringValue = "mod"; return(MULOP); }
and         {yylval.stringValue = "and"; return(MULOP); }
"*"         {yylval.stringValue = "*"; return(MULOP);   }
"/"         {yylval.stringValue = "/"; return(MULOP);   }
while       {return(WHILE);                             }
or          {return(OR);                                }
"+"         {yylval.stringValue = "+"; return(SIGN);    }
"-"         {yylval.stringValue = "-"; return(SIGN);    }
".."        {return(DOUBLEDOT);                         }
","         {return *yytext;                            }
"("         {return *yytext;                            }
")"         {return *yytext;                            }
"["         {return *yytext;                    }
"]"         {return *yytext;                    }
";"         {return *yytext;                                }
":"         {return *yytext;                                }
"."         {return *yytext;                                }
not         {return(NOT);                               }
{ID}        {yylval.stringValue= strdup(yytext); return(ID);}
%%
int yywrap(void){}
```

Here is my parser:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "SymbolTable.h"
    int errors;
    int lable;
    #define YYDEBUG 1

    install (char *sym_name)
    {
        symrec *s;
        s = getsym(sym_name);
        if (s == 0)
            s = putsym(sym_name);
        else {
            errors++;
            printf("%s is defined\n", sym_name);
        }
    }

    install_num (char *sym_name)
    {
        symrec *s;
        s = getsym(sym_name);
        if (s == 0)
            s = putnum(sym_name);
    }

    context_check(char *sym_name)
    {
        if (getsym(sym_name) == 0)
            printf("%s is undeclared\n", sym_name);
    }
%}
%union
{
    int intValue;
    float floatValue;
    char *stringValue;
    int adress;
}
%start program
%token <stringValue> ID
%token <stringValue> NUM
%token IF THEN PROGRAM VAR ARRAY
%token OF INTEGER REAL
%token FUNCTION PROCEDURE
%token START END
%token ASSIGNOP RELOP MULOP
%token ELSE WHILE DO
%token SIGN OR
%token DOUBLEDOT
%token NOT
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%%
program: PROGRAM ID '(' prog_list ')' ';' declarations subprogram_declarations compound_statement '.'
         ;
prog_list: ID
         | prog_list ',' ID
         ;
identifier_list: ID  {install($1);}
         | identifier_list ',' ID {install($3);} 
         ;
declarations: declarations VAR identifier_list ':' type ';'
         | /* empty */
         ;
type: standart_type
         | ARRAY '[' NUM DOUBLEDOT NUM ']' OF REAL {set_type("REALARR");}
         | ARRAY '[' NUM DOUBLEDOT NUM ']' OF INTEGER {set_type("INTARR");}
         ;
standart_type: INTEGER {set_type("INTEGER");}
         | REAL {set_type("REAL");}
         ;
subprogram_declarations: subprogram_declarations subprogram_declaration ';'
         | /* empty */
;
subprogram_declaration: subprogram_head declarations compound_statement;
subprogram_head: FUNCTION ID arguments ':' INTEGER ';' {install($2); set_type("INTEGER");}
         | FUNCTION ID arguments ':' REAL ';' {install($2); set_type("REAL");}
         | PROCEDURE ID arguments ';' {install($2); set_proc($2);}
         ;
arguments: '(' parameter_list ')'
         | /* empty */;
parameter_list: identifier_list ':' type
         | parameter_list ';' identifier_list ':' type
         ;
compound_statement: START
                    optional_statements END
         ;
optional_statements: statement_list
         | /* empty */
         ;
statement_list: statement
         | statement_list ';' statement
         ;
statement: variable ASSIGNOP expression
         | procedure_statement
         | compound_statement
         | IF expression THEN statement ELSE statement
         | WHILE expression DO statement
         ;
variable: ID {context_check($1);}
         | ID '[' expression ']' {context_check($1);}
         ;
procedure_statement: ID 
         | ID '(' expression_list ')'
         ;
expression_list: expression
         | expression_list ',' expression
         ;
expression: simple_expression
         | simple_expression RELOP simple_expression
         ;
simple_expression: term
         | SIGN term
         | simple_expression SIGN term
         | simple_expression OR term
         ;
term: factor
         | term MULOP factor
         ;
factor: variable
         | ID '(' expression_list ')' {context_check($1);}
         | NUM {install_num($1);}
         | '(' expression ')'
         | NOT factor
         ;
%%
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *output = fopen("output.asm", "w");
    fprintf(output, "\t  jump.i #lab0\n");
    extern FILE *yyin;
    ++argv; --argc;
    yyin = fopen(argv[0], "r");
    yydebug = 1;
    errors = 0;
    yyparse();
    print_sym_table();
    fprintf(output, "\t  exit");
    fclose(output);

}
yyerror (char *s) /* Called by yyparse on error */
{
    errors++;
    printf ("%s\n", s);
}
```

Here is symbol table:

```
struct symrec
{
    char *name;
    int addr;
    char *type;
    struct symrec *next; 
};
typedef struct symrec symrec;
symrec *sym_table = (symrec *)0;
symrec *putsym();
symrec *getsym();
symrec *putnum();
void set_type();
void set_proc();
void set_func();
void print_sym_table();

symrec *putsym(char *sym_name)
{
    symrec *ptr;
    ptr = (symrec *)malloc(sizeof(symrec));
    ptr->name = (char *)malloc(strlen(sym_name) + 1);
    ptr->type = NULL;
    strcpy(ptr->name,sym_name);
    ptr->next = (struct symrec *)sym_table;
    sym_table = ptr;
    return ptr;
}

symrec *putnum(char *sym_name)
{
    symrec *ptr;
    char *dPos = strchr(sym_name, '.');
    char *ePos = strchr(sym_name, 'e');
    ptr = (symrec *)malloc(sizeof(symrec));
    ptr->name = (char *)malloc(strlen(sym_name) + 1);
    if ((dPos == NULL) && (ePos == NULL)){
        ptr->type = (char *)malloc(strlen("INTEGER") + 1);
        strcpy(ptr->type, "INTEGER");
    }
    else if ((dPos != NULL) && (ePos == NULL)) {
        ptr->type = (char *)malloc(strlen("REAL") + 1);
        strcpy(ptr->type, "REAL");
    }
    else {
        ptr->type = (char *)malloc(strlen("FLOAT") + 1);
        strcpy(ptr->type, "FLOAT");
    }
    strcpy(ptr->name,sym_name);
    ptr->next = (struct symrec *)sym_table;
    sym_table = ptr;
    return ptr;
}

void set_type(char *type)
{
    symrec *ptr;
    for (ptr = sym_table; ptr != (symrec *)0; ptr = (symrec *)ptr->next) {
        if (ptr->type == NULL) {
            ptr->type = (char *)malloc(strlen(type) + 1);
            strcpy(ptr->type, type);
        }
    }
}

void set_proc(char *sym_name) {
    symrec *ptr;
    for (ptr = sym_table; ptr != (symrec *)0; ptr = (symrec *)ptr->next)
        if (strcmp (ptr->name, sym_name) == 0){
            ptr->type = (char *)malloc(strlen("PROC") + 1);
            strcpy(ptr->type, "PROC");
        }
}

symrec *getsym(char *sym_name)
{
    symrec *ptr;
    for (ptr = sym_table; ptr != (symrec *)0; ptr = (symrec *)ptr->next)
        if (strcmp (ptr->name, sym_name) == 0)
            return ptr;
    return 0;
}

void print_sym_table()
{
    symrec *ptr;
    for (ptr = sym_table; ptr != (symrec *)0; ptr = (symrec *)ptr->next)
        printf("\n%s    %s\n", ptr->name, ptr->type);
}
```

Simple test file

```
program example(input, output);
var x, y: integer;
var g,h:real;

begin
  g:=x+y;
  write(g)
end.
```

And what it should print to the output file:

```
     jump.i  #lab0                   ;jump.i  lab0
lab0:
        add.i   0,4,24                  ;add.i   x,y,$t0
        inttoreal.i 24,28               ;inttoreal.i $t0,$t1
        mov.r   28,8                    ;mov.r   $t1,g
        write.r 8                       ;write.r g
        exit                            ;exit
```

comments (;jump.i lab0) are not necessary.

I know how adresses of variables should be calculated and I can translate pascal code to this assembler on paper, but I really don't understand where and what should I put in bison or flex file so it would generate assembler code into output file. I've tried to generate labels for begin statements in rule :

```
compound_statement: START {fprintf(output, "lab0\n");}
                    optional_statements END
```

But it got segmentation fault. It's pretty obvious how to generate labels, but how should I generate

```
add.i 0, 4, 24
```

Should I create another parser after I've built symbol table with this one? Or is it doable without additional parser. Need some hints what to do next.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  You are asking an enormous question — one that is very broad, and IMO not one that can easily be answered on SO.  You have to work out what assembler code would represent the actions requested by the program.  You'll need to work out how space is managed, functions called, variables modified, etc — for all the statements and expressions that are a part of your dialect of Pascal.

Comment: I know what assembler code represents actions and how everything works, I just don't understand how to handle that using Bison and Flex, all I need is some hint on how to do it on that simple adding operation and how to write generated code to file, because as I've mentioned in the question if I add bison action fprintf it breaks with segmentation fault

Comment: You need a book on compilers.

Comment: Flex and Bison are tools that produce C source code.  Their outputs are intended to be compiled and linked into a program, via a C compiler.  Depending on what you include in your scanner and parser definitions, you may need to provide additional C code externally.  Usually, none of this involves producing *assembly* code as an output.  Rather, the result is a runnable program, in whatever format is appropriate for the machine.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it is very common for compilers to produce human-readable assembly output and then call the assembler to convert it to binary.

Comment: @n.m., it is uncommon for compilers to produce assembly *as an output*, at least by default, as opposed to producing it as an intermediate representation.  The point is that assembly is probably not what the OP should be expecting or trying to obtain.

Comment: It actually is as stated in my first sentence.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Assembly output is exactly what OP wants. It's a university assignment and it targets an imaginary architecture. Why on God's green earth would anyone want binary output for this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you've got this bit of code:

```
compound_statement: START {fprintf(output, "lab0\n");}
                    optional_statements END
```

You're on the right track doing it this way, but you get a segmentation fault when you add it in and this is because `output` isn't initialised.

I can't see where you've declared the `output` that is being referenced there, but it isn't the same one that is declared in `main` where you open a file for output.

```
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *output = fopen("output.asm", "w");
```

That version `output` is local to `main` and only visible inside that function. If you remove the declaration of `output` from `main` and leave just the assignment, you'll be assigning the results of `fopen` to the globally declared version of `output` that your bison code is using.

```
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    output = fopen("output.asm", "w");
```

Not sure why you're having confusion with the other part of your question since you've demonstrated how to do it already in your parser. Take this bit of your parser:

```
variable: ID {context_check($1);}
```

It is taking the value of "ID" - the `$1` - and passing it to that function. If you wanted "variable" to contain a value you'd store it in `$$`. Then when you use "variable" higher up like in here:

```
statement: variable ASSIGNOP expression
```

`$1` will contain whatever value you put in `$$` for "variable". `$2` will be the value obtained from "ASSIGNOP" token and `$3` will have the results from "expression". And again if you store a value in `$$` you'd be able to use it in anything that is expecting a "statement".

`$$`, `$1` etc... are all of the type you've created by using `%union`, so you can also do `$$.intValue` or `$2.stringValue` if you need to specifically state which value you're setting.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But the second part of the question is open, how do I generate asm code with flex/bison, I understand that for adding operation it must be done here:

simple_expression SIGN term

But how do I bring up values of simple_expression and term to lookup for them in symbol table, do I have to use $$ from bottom of the syntax tree to here? It's really confusing for me

Comment: Hopefully that update to my answer covers the rest of your confusion

Answer (score 2):

In your parser, for example, you have a pattern:

```
| term MULOP factor
```

You would like to put an action on that pattern that was something like:

```
{ fprintf(output, "mul term, factor, result\n"); }
```

but it starts to get sticky very quickly: where are term, factor and where should you put the result?
The easiest answer is a stack:  whenever an variable is referenced, push its value onto the stack.   whenever an operation is matched, pop the operand(s) into registers, perform the operation, and push the result, so the above becomes:

```
    {
   fprintf(output, "pop r0; pop r1; mul r1, r0, r0;");
   fprintf(output, "push r0\n");
}
```

and assignments just pop the stack into a variable.